# No matching function on Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

So I've been learning Boost.Python these days but I've faced this issue and can't understand why this happens nor how to fix it. A dummy code I've wrote in order to replicate this issue is the following:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

struct A {
private:
  double val;
public:
  A (double val) {
    this->val = val;
  }
  double get() {
    return this->val;
  }
  void set(double val) {
    this->val = val;
  }
};

struct B {
private:
  std::map<std::string, A> dict;
public:
  B ();
  double get(std::string key) {
    return this->dict[key].get();
  }
  void set(std::string key, double val) {
    this->dict[key] = A(val);
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(core) {
  class_<B>("B")
    .def("get", &B::get)
    .def("set", &B::set);
}
```

I'm using setuptools extensions in order to compile it, so the following compilation command is generated automatically:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/gabriel-milan/sandbox/BoostTest/ -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c BoostTest/core.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/BoostTest/core.o
```

Just in case you're wondering, my `setup.py` file looks like this:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.extension import Extension

extensions = [
  Extension(
    "BoostTest.core",
    sources=["BoostTest/core.cpp"],
    libraries=["boost_python3"],
  ),
]

setup (
  name='BoostTest',
  packages=find_packages(),
  ext_modules=extensions,
)
```

Finally, the output I get is the following:

```
...
BoostTest/core.cpp:30:26:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/tuple:1668:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
BoostTest/core.cpp:13:3: note: candidate: ‘A::A(double)’
   A (double val) {
   ^
BoostTest/core.cpp:13:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
BoostTest/core.cpp:9:8: note: candidate: ‘constexpr A::A(const A&)’
 struct A {
        ^
BoostTest/core.cpp:9:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
BoostTest/core.cpp:9:8: note: candidate: ‘constexpr A::A(A&&)’
BoostTest/core.cpp:9:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

In this case, I'd like that only `B` was exposed to Python. For that reason, `A` is not on `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`. Anyway, I've tried adding `A` there but it doesn't work. I'm pretty newbie to Boost.Python, can you guys please help me?

Answer (score 1):

In `B::get`, you have a one line `return this->dict[key].get();`. This is more complicated than you may initially think. In particular, the `[]` operator for a map will insert an element if it does not exist. For it to do this, it needs to be able to default construct this new element. Since your map stores `A` objects as values, your class `A` needs to be default constructable.

Simply add a default constructor to `class A`:

```
A(): val(0) { }
```

Comment: This probably solves the issue for this example I've given but, in cases where I need the object to be only constructed with arguments, will this work?

Comment: @GabrielMilan Then you'll need to look for elements in the map differently. Either using `dict.find(key)` (with appropriate handling should the key not be found), or `dict.at(key)` (which will throw an exception if the key isn't found).